# Search for a value in List of Objects

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have this Map which stores Map of Objects:

```
Map<String, ActiveConnections> cache = new LinkedHashMap<>();

public class ActiveConnections
    {

        private int one;
        private int two;
        private int three;

        public ActiveConnections(int one, int two, int three)
        {
            this.one = one;
            this.two = two;
            this.three = three;
        }

        public int getOne()
        {
            return one;
        }

        public void setOne(int one)
        {
            this.one = one;
        }

        public int getTwo()
        {
            return two;
        }

        public void setTwo(int two)
        {
            this.two = two;
        }

        public int getThree()
        {
            return three;
        }

        public void setThree(int three)
        {
            this.three = three;
        }

    }
```

How I can create a loop which searches for a value into the `Map` of Objects. For example I want to get all values `two = 4`.

Comment: Doing something like that beats the purpose of using a Map...

Comment: I don't get the point?

Comment: Map was made so you *won't* have to iterate the data-structure when you want to find an element. Map works in (theoretical) O(1). If you plan to iterate all the items you might as well use a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I posted in the comment above - using a Map to iterate the items beats the purpose of using a map, but if there are other restrictions that were not brought here and you have to use a map, I would implement a new search method in class `ActiveConnections`:

```
    public int search(int lookFor){
        int res = -1;//not found
        if(lookFor == one){
            res = one;
        }
        else if(lookFor == two){
            res = two;
        }
        else if(lookFor == three){
            res = three;
        }
        return res;        
    }
```

and then, for each item (active connection) - simply call search and validate that the result is not `-1` (or some other "error" code that you'll prefer).

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it iterates over all the key/value pairs in the map, looking for those with value `two == 4` in their `ActiveConnections`. Once found, you can decide what to do with the key, or the value in the `entry`, it's up to you.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ActiveConnections> entry : cache.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().getTwo() == 4) {
        // we found one, do something with the entry
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate through the values...

```
for (ActiveConnections value : cache.values()) {
    if (value.getTwo() == 4) {
        //logic
    }
}
```